# Iteration over references?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, pass-by-reference

I would like to perform the same operation on several arrays, something like:

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
int main(void){
    std::vector<double> a, b;
    for(auto& ab:{a,b}) std::sort(ab.begin(),ab.end()); // error 
}
```

This code fails, since `auto&` is a const-reference. Is there an elegant way around it?

Comment: @Lightness it's an `std::initializer_list<std::vector<double>>`. problem here is that the iterators of an initializer list are *always* `const`.

Comment: So there you go. I wonder whether some rvalue forwarding magic could help here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is that it's a bit like binding a temporary to a non-const reference. There is no "concrete" collection there so it is a bit like a temporary.

IF you have a temporary vector there, it will bind to a const reference but not a non-const one.

I also think this won't ever work what you are doing, but this should work:

```
#include<vector> 
#include<algorithm> 
int main(void)
{     
    std::vector<double> a, b;     
    for(std::vector<double>* ab:{&a,&b}) 
      std::sort(ab->begin(),ab->end()); // or begin(*ab),end(*ab)
}
```

and auto may work too.

Comment: Oh yes pointers solve it in an elegant way, thanks. And one can write both `auto` and `auto*` :-)

Comment: my immediate feeling of what you were doing was that even if you got it to compile, you'd effectively be sorting copies. That is why you're lucky in a way that the compiler stopped you.

Comment: @CashCow: Correct, `std::initializer_list` automatically copies.

Comment: I think the C++11 standard is that the compiler can optimise and substitute any copy with a move if a move is available and would work in the situation, i.e. the object is not re-used in its existing state. In this case you don't want your vectors a and b to be moved, you want them to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

> This code fails, *since auto& is a const-reference.* [emphasis mine]

Your reasoning doesn't hold. In a range-based for loop, what you declare (here, `auto& ab`) is *not* bound to the range expression (here, `{a,b }`). Instead, `ab` will be initialized from the *elements* of the range, not the range itself.

Instead the error stems from calling `std::sort` with parameters `ab.begin()`/`ab.end()`, which can easily be witnessed by commenting the body of the loop. As RMartinho has pointed out, the elements of the `std::initializer_list<std::vector<double>>` are immutable, and you can't sort a `const` container (`std::sort` shuffles elements using moves, can't assign to a `const` element).

Assuming you want to (independently) sort both vectors, you can do:

```
for(auto& ab: { std::ref(a), std::ref(b) })
    std::sort(std::begin(ab.get()), std::end(ab.get()));
```

Notice that according to template argument deduction rules, `auto&` is fine here and `auto` will be deduced to `const std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<double>>`, yielding `std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<double>> const&` as the type of `ab`.

Comment: I was thinking the same: you can't have a vector of references because it lacks the semantics but an initializer list of std::ref might well work for it, in which case you wouldn't need to dereference the pointers like I did. I am not sure you need auto&, auto might do fine as get() is a const member of a std::ref. Same way that mine works as I have const pointers but not pointers to const.

Comment: Is this a special feature of std::ref? Why isn't auto deduced to const std::ref_t<std::vector<double> > & on which you can call std::vector<double>& get() const

Comment: @CashCow My mistake, `std::vector<T>` doesn't have a `get` member and I did indeed wanted to refer to `std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<double>>`. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yes you're right it's reference_wrapper not ref_t. I quite like that your answer uses references although in some ways it's no less indirection than my solution with pointers.

Comment: @CashCow Indeed, `std::reference_wrapper<T>` advantages over `T*` are implicit construction from `T`, implicit conversion to `T&` and a forwarding `operator()`. None of those things matters here. I just used `std::ref` out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

I think CashCows solution is nice. Just to show a different way: You could also use variadic templates to solve this.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void mysort() {} // termination version

template<typename Arg1, typename... Args>
void mysort(Arg1 &arg1, Args&... args )
{
    sort(arg1.begin(), arg1.end());
    mysort(args...);
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<double> a, b;
    mysort(a, b);
}
```

@CashCow: It is possible to pass an algorithm as argument but it is a little bit ugly because of the use of decltype:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename Algo>
void mysort(Algo algo) {} // termination version

template<typename Algo, typename Arg1, typename... Args>
void mysort(Algo algo, Arg1 &arg1, Args&... args )
{
    algo(arg1.begin(), arg1.end());
    mysort(algo, args...);
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<double> a, b;
    mysort(&sort<decltype(a.begin())>, a, b);
}
```

Comment: Nice but can we add a lambda to your variadic template that allows us to put in the algorithm we want to call, i.e. modify the sort to any algorithm that takes a range. Incidentally doesn't sort work now on a range without having to specify being and end? Algorithms will automatically call that for you. I couldn't do that in my solution because it took pointers.

Comment: @CashCow see my edit for a version which takes an algorithm as parameter.